# Entry boxes automatic

Tags: python, tkinter, printing

The Entry boxes are created below the labels. I was trying to create it against each label

```
#!/bin/env /python
from Tkinter import *
import time
from datetime import datetime


akhilGui = Tk()
akhilGui.geometry('600x500')
month_list = ["April 2020","May 2020","June 2020", "July 2020","August 2020", "September 2020","October 2020","November2020", "December 2020", "January 2021","February 2021", "March 2021"] #initialise the variable row_value to be used in grid()
lab_list = []
entry_list =[]
def lab_print ():
        monthyear = time.strftime("%m%Y")
        k= int(monthyear[:2])
        if k < 4:
                k=k+12
        else:
                k= k
        month_lab = month_list[:k-4]        

        row_value = 5
        for i in month_lab: #iterating through the list, creating label
        #iLabel          = str(i) + "Label"
        #iEntry          = str(i) + "Entry"
            
            row_value = row_value + 1
            iLabel          = Label(akhilGui, text= str(i),
                                fg="#113B53",font = "Helvetica  12 bold ", justify='right')
            lab_list.append(iLabel)
            iLabel.grid(row = row_value, column=0, pady=2, padx=15, sticky= W)
            row_value = row_value+1

         v               = StringVar(akhilGui, value='0')

        for i in range (8):
            iEntry          = Entry(akhilGui, bd =1, fg= "#093145",
                                textvariable = v,justify='right')
            iEntry.grid(row= row_value, column=1, pady=2,sticky= W)
            row_value       = row_value + 1
lab_print ()

akhilGui.mainloop()
```

Kindly spot where I am wrong! Help is awaited!I am trying to achieve a column of months for the financial year except the current month and an entry box against each of the to post an amount in each box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from datetime import datetime

def lab_print ():
        current_year = time.strftime("%Y")
        current_month = datetime.now().strftime('%B')
        current_month_year = ' '.join([current_month,current_year])
        
        for x in range(len(month_list)):

            if  month_list[x] != current_month_year:
                Label(root, text=month_list[x]).grid(row=x, column=0)
                Entry(root).grid(row=x, column=1)
                Grid.rowconfigure(root,  x, weight=1)
            
            else:
                break  

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x500')

Grid.columnconfigure(root, (0,1), weight=1)

month_list = ["April 2020","May 2020","June 2020", "July 2020","August 2020", "September 2020","October 2020","November2020", "December 2020", "January 2021","February 2021", "March 2021"] #initialise the variable row_value to be used in grid()

lab_list = []
entry_list =[]

lab_print ()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If we are doing it during december the labels should be April 2020 to November 2020. If in January2021  it sholuld be from April 2020  to December 2020.

Comment: your answer is super!